# creating & Inserting image thumbnail in oracle through php

Tags: php

Will some one please help me with the code of creating & Inserting image thumbnail in oracle through php.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save an image to the database, you'll be using BLOBs (Binary Large Objects) or BFILES. [Oracle+PHP Cookbook](http://www.oracle.com/technology/pub/articles/oracle_php_cookbook/fuecks_lobs.html) contains some information about using these. With BLOBS you write the binary representation of the image to the database. With BFILES you save the image to the file system and store a link to the image to the database.

As for creating thumbnails, there some reading to be done about [GD and image functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php) in PHP. You'll want to watch out for large images as these functions require a lot of available memory. Particularly in hosted environments, the you might need to give some extra memory to the active PHP interpreter process make it possible to create thumbnails.

For image resizing, please check similar questions already found in Stack Overflow i.e.

- [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12661/efficient-jpeg-image-resizing-in-php)
- [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22259/how-do-i-resize-and-convert-an-uploaded-image-to-a-png-using-gd)
- [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907361/show-image-from-blob-mysql)
- and so on.