# Convert Images with PHP without using ImageMagick

Tags: php, image, png, jpeg

I need to convert a .JPG, .JPEG, .JPE, .GIF, etc to a .PNG from my PHP webpage without using ImageMagick. Any ideas?

---

**Here is the code I found and am trying to work with:**

```
<?php
header("content-type: image/png");
$original_filename = $_HTTP_POST_FILES['uploaded_file']; 
imagepng($original_filename,'border/testconvert.png',9);

?>
```

Comment: Only one: GD. http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php

Comment: I've been looking through the GD documentation, but couldn't figure it out. I've tried some examples I found online, I'll edit my original post and append the code.

Comment: Already a question about this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22259/how-do-i-resize-and-convert-an-uploaded-image-to-a-png-using-gd

Comment: You can't just take a file *path* and make it into a PNG image. String != Image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Who needs ImageMagick? Take a look at the built-in [image functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) using gd.

**EDIT** Basic example:

```
<?php
 $filename = "myfolder/test.jpg";
 $jpg = @imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
 if ($jpg)
 {
   header("Content-type: image/png");
   imagepng($jpg);
   imagedestroy($jpg);
   exit;
 }

 // JPEG couldn't be loaded, maybe show a default image
?>
```

You can do more with this such as change compression and quality values etc, save the output to a file instead of outputting to the browser and so on - check the docs for further info :-)

Note that the image functions issue warnings/notices etc if there are problems loading an image, hence the use of the @ symbol to suppress, otherwise you'll get spurious output instead of just the image data.

Comment: gd is not always available either.  You need to compile PHP with `--with-gd`.

Comment: I can use GD, I've used it with other image manipulation tasks I had. I just can't figure out how to convert the images.

Comment: And if you're allowing multiple file types, you'll have to setup a check to see what the extension is and run a switch to load the image based on its file type or just load a default image if it doesn't match anything.

Comment: This will do just fine! Thanks!

Comment: Re the @ -- it would be much better to turn errors off for the page altogether (`error_reporting(0);`).  Suppressing individual errors dramatically slows performance, even when no errors occur.

Comment: OK, your example works perfectly. But, I can't seem to find anything about converting .BMP to .PNG... any ideas?

Comment: Who needs imagemagick? Anyone that wants a very simple solution to otherwise bulky image handling. Yeah you don't NEED it, but it is a very useful tool for so many reasons. It improved the productivity of our firm substantially with easy to understand, single line conversions.

Comment: @Kai I don't doubt it - it is a useful tool.  The OP asked for a solution that didn't use it however :-)

Comment: @richsage: I am trying to covert from webp to jpg.Followed your snippet,but I am getting yellow background in the converted pic.What could be the reason.Pls assist..

Answer (score 0):

```
function jpg2png($originalFile, $outputFile, $quality) {
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($originalFile);
    imagepng($image, $outputFile, $quality);
    imagedestroy($image);
}
```

Try something like this.

Tell me if if works!!

Good luck

Comment: It was the same logic (ish) used in the first example, and yes.. it works great! But, would you happen to know about converting .BMP to .PNG?

Comment: No but you should really start a question on that particular topic because might be really interesting. Good luck!