# php image resize and convert to jpg on upload

Tags: php, resize, image-conversion

How to resize an image and convert to .jpg on upload? Basically something like the post here

[How do I resize and convert an uploaded image to a PNG using GD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22259/how-do-i-resize-and-convert-an-uploaded-image-to-a-png-using-gd)

But i need to convert to JPG...

I tried `imagejpeg()` instead of `imagepng()` but it still saves it as png.

Comment: Just save the file as a jpg instead of png, [`imagejpeg`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php)

Comment: I tried that but it did not work. It still saves as png.

Comment: You should put that in your question and the code you tried but failed.

Answer (score 1):

It that thread that you linked to, the accepted answer is converting to png like this:

`imagepng($newImage, $destFile);`

Your code would need to be only slightly different:

`imagejpg($newImage, $destFile);`

See the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060835/how-to-convert-all-images-to-jpg-format-in-php) for further reference:

Answer (score 0):

there is a ready to use class, u could try - http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

You could apply:

```
imagejpeg($this->image,$filename,$compression);
```